# Migration assistant fills disk before finishing

Tags: high-sierra, migration-assistant

I'm trying to migrate 200GB to an older MacBook pro.  Both are running High Sierra.  Migration Assistant tells me 270GB will be unallocated after the migration.  It continues to fail.  In all cases it has filled up the disk entirely.  Is there a setting I should consider before trying again???

Comment: Did you reformat the internal HD of the target MacBook Pro?

Comment: @IconDaemon no.  Why does it matter?

Comment: Misread the question. How much free space is on the target MBP? On which drive will 270GB be unallocated? What, exactly, are you using MA to transfer?

Comment: @iconDaemon there is about 500gb of free space on the on the target. I am transferring two parallels VMs. Each of which are roughly 100gb.

Comment: You may want to transfer these VM files directly using Terminal commands instead of Migration Assistant.

Comment: @IconDaemon It may come to that.  I will have to wait for the disk to decrypt before sending raw files (current duration still reads: "more than a day remaining").  I could encrypt and transfer 500GB of AES+CBC encrypted data in less than a day.  So lets hope it won't be that long lol!